# SQL Server Agent Restrictions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package which contains a C# script used to invoke an SFTP executable with arguments.  This script really only calls the executable with arguments and downloads a set of files.  This part works flawlessly when I run it in visual studio, or execute the package manually on the server through integration services.  However, when I assign an agent to run this package the executable is never run.  I've watched it and the executable is never even started.  Is there some way an agent would be unable to execute a C# script within a package that contains a section of code to call an executable?

I don't expect it to be a file path issue because I can right click and select "Run Package" in integration services on that same server and it will work.

Comment: If I have been at all unclear please let me know.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run it in SQL Agent:

1. It runs on the SQL Server, not locally (i.e. not on the client machine)
2. It runs as the SQL Agent user

When you right click on the package in the SSIS Service, it actually also runs locally, not on the SQL Server. (at least up to the 2008 version - I don't know about newer versions)

The answer is in your SSIS Log - does it reach the task? What's the message when it gets there? If you don't have logging, turn it on and check it.

Can you clarify whether the SQL Server is remote, what version of SQL Server you're using, and what the SSIS log says for that step.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using SQL Server 2012, and while I am remoting into the machine via remote desktop to develop the package I am also uploading the package to the same machine from said machine.

Comment: The logs have only this information that I have found related to the SFTP section: OnPreExecute,\svcSqlAgent,Acquire Files,{blahblahblah},10/2/2013 6:07:10 PM,10/2/2013 6:07:10 PM,0,0x,
OnPostExecute,\svcSqlAgent,Acquire Files,{blahblahblah},10/2/2013 6:07:10 PM,10/2/2013 6:07:10 PM,0,0x,

Comment: Is your SFTP task called 'Acquire Files'? What is the blah blah? It appears it is getting to the step and running it anyway. You could temporarily set the SQL Agent Service account to your login to rule in or out a security issue. For example if the SQL Agent Service is at it's default (Local\System) it will not be able to get to any remote drives. (SFTP doesnt use remote drives). Also the 'secure' part of SFTP may require it to be run as a certain user.

Comment: Also if your SFTP client has logging, enable it also. You will only get to the bottom of this by studying logs. You might also find some info already in the windows event logs.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely points me in the direction I need; learning more about logging.  Again, thank you for all of your assistance.